# How to set component orientation from right to left in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, components, midlet

I just need to know how a component orientation can be set **from right to left in j2me**. For instance writing is starting from right to left in some languages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use LAYOUT_RIGHT option, try running below code,

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package hello;

import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

/**
 * @author root
 */
public class HelloMIDlet extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

    private boolean midletPaused = false;

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Fields ">
    private Command exitCommand;
    private Form form;
    private StringItem stringItem;
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * The HelloMIDlet constructor.
     */
    public HelloMIDlet() {
    }

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Methods ">
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: initialize ">
    /**
     * Initilizes the application.
     * It is called only once when the MIDlet is started. The method is called before the <code>startMIDlet</code> method.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        // write pre-initialize user code here

        // write post-initialize user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: startMIDlet ">
    /**
     * Performs an action assigned to the Mobile Device - MIDlet Started point.
     */
    public void startMIDlet() {
        // write pre-action user code here
        switchDisplayable(null, getForm());
        // write post-action user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: resumeMIDlet ">
    /**
     * Performs an action assigned to the Mobile Device - MIDlet Resumed point.
     */
    public void resumeMIDlet() {
        // write pre-action user code here

        // write post-action user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: switchDisplayable ">
    /**
     * Switches a current displayable in a display. The <code>display</code> instance is taken from <code>getDisplay</code> method. This method is used by all actions in the design for switching displayable.
     * @param alert the Alert which is temporarily set to the display; if <code>null</code>, then <code>nextDisplayable</code> is set immediately
     * @param nextDisplayable the Displayable to be set
     */
    public void switchDisplayable(Alert alert, Displayable nextDisplayable) {
        // write pre-switch user code here
        Display display = getDisplay();
        if (alert == null) {
            display.setCurrent(nextDisplayable);
        } else {
            display.setCurrent(alert, nextDisplayable);
        }
        // write post-switch user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Method: commandAction for Displayables ">
    /**
     * Called by a system to indicated that a command has been invoked on a particular displayable.
     * @param command the Command that was invoked
     * @param displayable the Displayable where the command was invoked
     */
    public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {
        // write pre-action user code here
        if (displayable == form) {
            if (command == exitCommand) {
                // write pre-action user code here
                exitMIDlet();
                // write post-action user code here
            }
        }
        // write post-action user code here
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Getter: exitCommand ">
    /**
     * Returns an initiliazed instance of exitCommand component.
     * @return the initialized component instance
     */
    public Command getExitCommand() {
        if (exitCommand == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 0);
            // write post-init user code here
        }
        return exitCommand;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Getter: form ">
    /**
     * Returns an initiliazed instance of form component.
     * @return the initialized component instance
     */
    public Form getForm() {
        if (form == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            form = new Form("Welcome", new Item[] { getStringItem() });
            form.addCommand(getExitCommand());
            form.setCommandListener(this);
            // write post-init user code here
        }
        return form;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Getter: stringItem ">
    /**
     * Returns an initiliazed instance of stringItem component.
     * @return the initialized component instance
     */
    public StringItem getStringItem() {
        if (stringItem == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            stringItem = new StringItem("Hello", "Hello, World!");
            stringItem.setLayout(ImageItem.LAYOUT_RIGHT);
            // write post-init user code here
        }
        return stringItem;
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /**
     * Returns a display instance.
     * @return the display instance.
     */
    public Display getDisplay () {
        return Display.getDisplay(this);
    }

    /**
     * Exits MIDlet.
     */
    public void exitMIDlet() {
        switchDisplayable (null, null);
        destroyApp(true);
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    /**
     * Called when MIDlet is started.
     * Checks whether the MIDlet have been already started and initialize/starts or resumes the MIDlet.
     */
    public void startApp() {
        if (midletPaused) {
            resumeMIDlet ();
        } else {
            initialize ();
            startMIDlet ();
        }
        midletPaused = false;
    }

    /**
     * Called when MIDlet is paused.
     */
    public void pauseApp() {
        midletPaused = true;
    }

    /**
     * Called to signal the MIDlet to terminate.
     * @param unconditional if true, then the MIDlet has to be unconditionally terminated and all resources has to be released.
     */
    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }

}
```

Comment: LAYOUT_RIGHT is unlikely what is asked about - question seem to be about [Right-to-left](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) writing orientation like in Hebrew/Arabic

Comment: Thanks for answer, I solved it by using Graphics to draw inverse into textbox.